# Can I just unzip and use Ractivejs? (build error)

Tags: ractivejs

Why need I build it? It's just JS

build error, help please.

```html
[apple@simple ractive]$ npm install
npm WARN package.json gobble-esperanto@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@1.0.2 should be installed with -g
[apple@simple ractive]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to use Ractive is to download a ready-made build (e.g. http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js or http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.min.js) or install it to your project with `npm install ractive` - you don't need to build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks，and another question， where can I get the complete code of sample of the Ractive site?

Comment: [Here you go](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractivejs.org) - all the sites are under the [RactiveJS organisation](https://github.com/ractivejs/) on GitHub